# Can I really trust LOG4J Timestamps for performance metrics in Production?

Tags: java, performance, logging, log4j

In the office next to where my Web app is hosted, LOG4J shows that a typical operation tested locally takes < 1 sec,

```
07 Nov 2019 12:30:01,860 INFO  ParticipantServiceImpl(Line 272) - User 1: Operation Start
...
07 Nov 2019 12:30:02,796 INFO  ParticipantServiceImpl(Line 881) - User 1: Operation End
```

The Production LOG4J shows that with many concurrent users connecting across the world on their phones, the operation average is closer to 5-7 sec. The output is often mixed up and out of order, but I'm concerned about the **timestamps**: Are the timestamps themselves reliable (even if out of order)? Do I indeed have a performance problem in the real user experience, or can LOG4J have some flushing or concurrency delay?

```
07 Nov 2019 12:30:01,860 INFO  ParticipantServiceImpl(Line 272) - User 1: Operation Start
07 Nov 2019 12:31:01,860 INFO  ParticipantServiceImpl(Line 272) - User 2: Operation Start
...
07 Nov 2019 12:37:02,796 INFO  ParticipantServiceImpl(Line 881) - User 1: Operation End
```

LOG4J configured as

```
    <RollingFile name="file" fileName="/local/content/tomcat/app/logs/app.log" append="true"
        filePattern="/local/content/tomcat/app/logs/app.log.%i"> 
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{DATE} %-5p %c{1}(Line %L) - %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>    
    <Logger name="com.app" level="debug">
    <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor" level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="file" />
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.springframework.orm" level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="file" />
    </Logger>    

    <Logger name="org.hibernate.engine.transaction" level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="console" />
    </Logger>   

    <Logger name="net.sf.ehcache" level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="file" />
    </Logger>

    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation of **Log4j**, I think you can trust it, but first you need to add the thread name to the appender so that you know which start and end times belong to which thread.

> **Property name**: log4j2.clock
>
> **Environment variable**: LOG4J_CLOCK
>
> **Default value**: SystemClock
>
> **Descrption**:
> Implementation of the org.apache.logging.log4j .core.util.Clock interface that is used for timestamping the log events.
> By default, System.currentTimeMillis is called on every log event.
> You can also specify a fully qualified class name of a custom class that implements the Clock interface.

The fact that the timestamps are out of order tells us that those are not timestamps of the logs being written but of the log events happening.

#### A differnt approach

I woud personally (apart from logging the start and end times - or maybe not log them at all) add a log event that writes the duraction of the task. That makes it easier to read, visually by humans and programatically (if you want to collect and analyze the data).

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
// perfom the task
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
LOG.info("Duration: " + (endTime - startTime)); // you can also convert milliseconds to hours,minutes, secconds
```